# Como movimentar texturas usando a libGdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

Fiz esse exemplo de código que desenha uma textura na tela do usuário:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx..graphics.g2d.*;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{
    TextureRegion image;
    @Override
    public void create(){
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("stick.png"));
        image = new TextureRegion(texture, 25, 0, 250, 250);

    }
    @Override
    public void render(){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        batch.end();

    }
    public void dispose(){
        batch.dispose();
    }
    public void resize(int width, int height){

    }
    public void pause(){

    }
    public void resume(){

    }

}
```

Como faço pra movimentá-la para as coordenadas que eu der?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione um atributo do tipo *Vector2* à classe *MyGdxGame* para representar a posição da textura
No método `create()` crie uma instância contendo a sua posição inicial:

```
private Vector2 texturePosition;
TextureRegion image;

@Override
public void create(){
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("stick.png"));
    image = new TextureRegion(texture, 25, 0, 250, 250);

    texturePosition = new Vector2(100,100);
}
```

No método `draw()`, passe os valores `x`e `y` de `texturePosition` ao método `batch.draw`:

```
batch.draw(image, texturePosition.x, texturePosition.y);
```

Declare um método para alterar a posição da textura:

```
private void moveTextureTo(float x, float y){

    texturePosition.x = x;
    texturePosition.y = y;
}
```

Quando quiser mover a textura chame esse método:

```
moveTextureTo(120, 120);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta funcionou bem ;)